# First Order Logic Example of Halting Problem

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand the halting problem better. What would be a few examples of some first order formulas that express a halting problem? Any responses would be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: If you want a sentence in the language of *arithmetic*, such a sentence is terribly complicated, since we have to encode Turing machine computations using only $+$, $\times$, and logical symbols.

Comment: Example in code then?

Comment: Again quite complicated, too complicated for a satisfactory answer.

Comment: if you have any ideas or could explain in words , would help

Comment: Take a look at the following file http://www.math.psu.edu/simpson/courses/math457/trakh.ps

Comment: this does not work for me :(

Comment: www.math.psu.edu/simpson/courses/math457/trakh.ps

Answer (score 1):

Just think about 'Turing machines' as programs of some programming language. Then  the halting problem would mean such a program $\mathcal H$ which inputs a *source code* of a program $\mathcal P$ and an input word $w$, and outputs 'YES' or 'NO' according that whether $\mathcal P$ halts on input $w$ or falls in infinite cycle.

If it existed, $\mathcal H$ would have a source code, and we can hack it (producing $\mathcal H'$) so that falls in infinite cycle at all places where $\mathcal H$ displayed 'YES', and before processing the input strings, overwrite the second one with the first one double. Say, there is a special character `,` to split the inputs of $\mathcal H$, `input1` and `input2`, and it is important to refer to it somehow in the language, say by a constant term `comma`. Then before any use of `input2`, insert the line

> input2:=input1+ comma +input1;

So that, if $p$ is the source code of $\mathcal P$, then
$\mathcal H'(p,w)$ doesn't halt $\iff \mathcal H(p,(p,p))=$'YES' $\iff\ \mathcal P$ halts on input $p,p$.

Now  $\mathcal P:=\mathcal H'$ and $w:={\rm code}(\mathcal H')$ for the contradiction: does or does not
$\mathcal H'(w,w)$ halt?